# Why in the world did someone make a 'book-of-hebrews' tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

This goes against the whole book naming paradigm, each book should get its own tag, which is the name of the book.  I guess this will be a tag-synonym request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a great question, Lance, and it was something that nobody really wanted to do. The problem is that somebody had already created a [hebrew](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew) tag, which is perfectly reasonable, but SE automatically corrects [hebrews](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrews) to [hebrew](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew).

Everyone who happened to be in chat at the time seemed to agree we could use a [book-of-hebrews](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-hebrews) tag for the time being, and once we get moderators, we can make a proper [hebrews](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrews) tag. It looks like SE has appointed two pro-tem moderators, so I would expect that it would not be long before you see this situation rectified.

It looks like Richard has created the [hebrews](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrews) tag, so I retagged the questions that were tagged [book-of-hebrews](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book-of-hebrews).

Comment: Is this still happening?  I was able to make a hebrews tag, but it could be because of the moderatorship thingy (I believe that's the technical term).  If this is still a problem, I'm wondering if we should leave it as it is...

Comment: Yes, it does look like we have both now, thanks to your moderatorship, so I suppose I'm answering "how did this come about". I guess now we need a tag synonym?

Comment: Uhh... I didn't do anything!  :P  It makes me question the original problem--whether it was a browser auto-correct, or that auto-choosing thing that comes from SE.  Huh.. OK, odd.  I'll approve the synonym.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it told me that it wouldn't allow the tag. Anyway, glad we have an actual hebrews tags now.